# Missing sub partition in System generated partition from sub partition template

Tags: oracle11g, partitioning

I am facing one issue but that is not being replicated on sample schema.
This is sample to explain my original case.
Suppose I have created below table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_SUB_TEMPLATE 
(
  DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(100), 
  LOCATION_ID NUMBER
)
 PARTITION BY RANGE(LOCATION_ID) INTERVAL(1)
 SUBPARTITION BY LIST(DEPT_NAME)
 SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE
 (
    SUBPARTITION HR VALUES ('HR'),
    SUBPARTITION MARKETING VALUES ('MARKETING'),
    SUBPARTITION DEVELOPMENT VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT'),
    SUBPARTITION TESTING VALUES ('TESTING')
 )
(
  PARTITION P0 VALUES LESS THAN (1) 
  (  
    SUBPARTITION P0_HR VALUES ('HR'),
    SUBPARTITION P0_MARKETING VALUES ('MARKETING'),
    SUBPARTITION P0_DEVELOPMENT VALUES ('DEVELOPMENT'),
    SUBPARTITION P0_TESTING VALUES ('TESTING')
  )
)
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
```

When I insert record below record the system generated partition is missing sub partition P0_DEVELOPMENT VALUES.

```
INSERT INTO emp_sub_template VALUES('HR',1001);
```

[image]

Suppose the highlighted subpartition is missing in system generated partition.
What could cause to miss a sub partition that is defined in sub partition template.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying this demo works, and the subpartitions are created; but you have a real situation that seems not to?

Comment: yes.. this demo is working correctly.. but in one real scenario it is not working.... and I couldn't replicate that issue anywhere else

Comment: Was a subpartition added to the table after the partition you're looking at was created, perhaos? (I have no idea off-hand if that's possible or what should happen if it is...).

Comment: no all subpartition was created from subparition template. In real scenario, the DDL is similar expect much more columns and sub parition values